# How to use hook_node_access in Drupal 8

Tags: drupal

How to use `hook_node_access()` in Drupal 8? I am new in Drupal World as well as Drupal 8.

This may be a repeated question ( sorry for that ). But I cannot find any proper answer

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to achieve with `hook_node_access`

Answer (score 1):

It is documented on the [Drupal website](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_access/8.9.x), e.g.:

```
use Drupal\Core\Access\AccessResult;
use Drupal\Core\Session\AccountInterface;
use Drupal\node\NodeInterface;

/**
 * Implements hook_node_access().
 */
function modulename_node_access(NodeInterface $node, $op, AccountInterface $account) {
  // Prevent any deletions.
  if ($op === 'delete') {
    return AccessResult::forbidden();
  }
 
  return AccessResult::neutral();
}
```

Comment: The link in your answer is dead.

Answer (score 0):

The explicit hook_node_access has been superseded by hook_ENTITY_TYPE_access in Drupal 9

See [hook_ENTITY_TYPE_access](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/function/hook_ENTITY_TYPE_access/9.4.x).

You can see how it is used in core/modules/node/node.module where node_node_access would be yourmodulename_node_access.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_ENTITY_TYPE_access().
 */
function node_node_access(NodeInterface $node, $op, AccountInterface $account) {
  $type = $node->bundle();

  // Note create access is handled by hook_ENTITY_TYPE_create_access().
  switch ($op) {
    case 'update':
      $access = AccessResult::allowedIfHasPermission($account, 'edit any ' . $type . ' content');
      if (!$access->isAllowed() && $account->hasPermission('edit own ' . $type . ' content')) {
        $access = $access->orIf(AccessResult::allowedIf($account->id() == $node->getOwnerId())->cachePerUser()->addCacheableDependency($node));
      }
      break;

    case 'delete':
      $access = AccessResult::allowedIfHasPermission($account, 'delete any ' . $type . ' content');
      if (!$access->isAllowed() && $account->hasPermission('delete own ' . $type . ' content')) {
        $access = $access->orIf(AccessResult::allowedIf($account->id() == $node->getOwnerId()))->cachePerUser()->addCacheableDependency($node);
      }
      break;

    default:
      $access = AccessResult::neutral();
  }

  return $access;
}
```